# What is the protocol of GPS tracking device TK103?

Tags: gps, location

I am currently working on getting a location of a vehicle to a server. I am using TK103 as my GPS device. It is sending `##,imei:<my_imei>,A;` to the server when the server is started.

This is the only document of the protocol I could find on internet: https://web.archive.org/web/20140401000000*/http://www.zhyichina.com/en/gpstracking/gprs-data-protocol.xls

I followed it. But it does not work properly. It needs to send "ON" command many times to work and any of other commands did not work. Could you please help me to identify the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you get message like **##,imei:123456789012345,A;** you need to respond with **LOAD**.

When you receive just IMEI number like **123456789012345;** you need to respond with **ON**.

Here you can find the source code of the decoder for this protocol:
https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/blob/master/src/org/traccar/protocol/Gps103ProtocolDecoder.java

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did the first two things, Sending LOAD and ON after "##,imei:123456789012345,A;" and "123456789012345;".
It worked once after I sent "ON" 3 times. So I made the code below to manually send them with command promp, so I can specifically send them. But it did not work.
1. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did the first two things, Sending LOAD and ON after "##,imei:123456789012345,A;" and "123456789012345;".
It worked once after I sent "ON" 3 times. So I made the code below to manually send them with command promp, so I can specifically send them. But it did not work.
1. How can I solve this problem ?
2. Is there a way to replace the "fix030s003n123456" command which I have to send via SMS with a command send by server without SMS ?
Here is the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4rlmhvuMNKgU01KQkYzY0hhRTQ/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Hope this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39828676/1744176 will help someone.